# Unexpected results with ddplyr in R

Tags: r, plyr

Just started using ddplyr {plyr} and I'm experiencing the following issue:

I create a simple data frame:

```
require(plyr)
df <- data.frame(day=c('monday', 'tuesday'), week=c(47,48))
```

Now when I run this:

```
ddply(df, .(day), transform,
  b = ifelse(week==47, week, day)
)
```

I get this:

```
      day week  b
1  monday   47 47
2 tuesday   48  2
```

Whereas I'm trying to get this:

```
      day week        b
1  monday   47       47
2 tuesday   48  tuesday
```

I think part of the problem is that I'm mixing numeric and string variables in one column. Any idea how I can get my intended result? Thanks!

Comment: If you treat both day and week as character, you get the expected outcome. At least I get the expected outcome in that way with my Mac.

Comment: try to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your call to `data.frame`

Comment: This gave me the expected result in linux mint `ddply(df, .(day), transform, b= ifelse(week==47, as.character(week), as.character(day)))` as @jazzurro mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @DominicComtois thanks but this didn't work (on a Mac, at least)

Comment: @akrun thanks that works! Unfortunately I have several ifelse statements in my code, so I'll have to add as.character() in all these places :)

Comment: @Rez99 In the data showed, the grouping variable is not needed to get the expected result.  It may be the case in your original dataset. `df[cbind(1:nrow(df), with(df, week==47) +1L)]#[1] "47"      "tuesday"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you didn't get the expected results by setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`... Here's what I get:

```
require(plyr)

df1 <- data.frame(day=c('monday', 'tuesday'), week=c(47,48), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
df2 <- data.frame(day=c('monday', 'tuesday'), week=c(47,48), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ddply(df1, .(day), transform,
  b = ifelse(week==47, week, day)
)

#       day week  b
# 1  monday   47 47
# 2 tuesday   48  2


ddply(df2, .(day), transform,
  b = ifelse(week==47, week, day)
)

#       day week       b
# 1  monday   47      47
# 2 tuesday   48 tuesday
```

You'd get the same if you converted the factor in df1 this way:

```
df1$day <- as.character(df1$day)
ddply(df1, .(day), transform,
  b = ifelse(week==47, week, day)
)
#       day week       b
# 1  monday   47      47
# 2 tuesday   48 tuesday
```

Comment: Thanks - that's interesting because I get different results when I run your exact code.  
  
When i run ddply on df2 I get:  
`#      day week  b  
#1  monday   47 47  
#2 tuesday   48  1`
I get the precisely the same result when I convert the factor in df1 too. I'm using {plyr} v 1.8.1 and Mac OS 10.9.5

Comment: Hmmm intreaguing.... when you just print `df2`, do you see anything unexpected? (btw I use R 3.1.2, plyr 1.8.1)

Comment: @akrun actually I just did in an edit to my previous comment!

Comment: @DominicComtois - no `df2` looks fine :)

Comment: I used `R 3.1.3` on `plyr _1.8.1`  and `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`
and I tested this on a fresh session with only `plyr` loaded.  So, i don't know why it is not working

Comment: Seems to be OS related... Just tried on Linux and get the same results as you guys (whereas first I was using Win7). I can't figure where the "1" comes from, instead of "tuesday"... :S